# Guidance on interactions in SEM using Lavaan (probe2WayMC): fixing intercepts and valProbe

Tags: interaction, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I’m relatively new to SEM and interactions within SEM, so this is a request pertaining to the validity of my syntax/approach, rather than troubleshooting.

My model has an IV (age, observed), DV (performance, latent), and moderator (climate, latent). I wish to probe interactions to understand whether the relationship between age and performance changes at different levels of climate. I'm using `semTools` to fit a model to a list of imputed datasets, and I've used `indProd` to make products of indicators using mean-centering. Because my age variable is observed, I’ve loaded it as a single indicator onto a latent factor.

```
MODERATION3 <- '

TP =~ TP1 + TP2 + TP3

SOC =~ SOC1 + SOC2 + SOC3 + SOC4

SA =~ SAI

 

SA.SOC =~ SAI.SOC1 + SAI.SOC2 + SAI.SOC3 + SAI.SOC4

SA.SOC ~~ SA + SOC

 

TP ~ SA + SOC + SA.SOC



TP1 ~ 0*1

TP ~ 1’
```

```
fit3 <- sem.mi(MODERATION3,
               data = mice.imp1,
               std.lv = FALSE,
               meanstructure = TRUE)
```

I noticed in the R documentation that for `probe2wayMC` all latent means are identified by fixing the the intercept of the first indicator of each to 0. Forgive my naivety, but why is this? I only did this for the DV as I thought that if an intercept is the value of y when x=0, then both the latent means of the IV and mod should be fixed to 0 while the latent mean of the DV should be freely estimated.

```
probe1 <- probe2WayMC(fit3, c("SA", "SOC", "SA.SOC"), "TP", "SOC",

                     c(-sqrt(1.046),0, sqrt(1.046)))  ## +/-1 square root of the mod estimated variance
```

```
$SimpleIntcept

    SOC   est   se     z      pvalue

1 -1.023 3.584 0.066 54.596      0

2  0.000 3.824 0.047 80.998      0

3  1.023 4.064 0.066 61.912      0
```

```
$SimpleSlope

    SOC   est   se     z    pvalue

1 -1.023 0.324 0.098 3.318  0.001

2  0.000 0.167 0.069 2.408  0.016

3  1.023 0.010 0.095 0.100  0.920
```

I then plotted the interaction using the min (1) and max (5) observed values of the IV.

```
plotProbe(probe1, xlim = c(1,5), xlab = "SAI", ylab = "TP")
```

[image: Plot]

Any feedback is very much appreciated,

Ben

Comment: There is only 1 question in your post, and I don't think it matters how you identify the mean structure. I think the author just wanted an example in which all the latent means/intercepts were estimated rather than fixed.

Comment: Hi @Terrence, thanks for the response.

Yes, I mentioned at the top that this was more about the validity of the approach rather than troubleshooting. 

If all looks OK with the approach and it does not make any difference which intercepts are/are not fixed in interactions then I will continue as-is. 

Best, Ben.